# Start process in C++ on linux with enviroment variable C++

Tags: c++, linux, environment-variables

How to start process on linux in C++ with enviroment variable `LD_PRELOAD=/test/lib.so`, i know that i should use function `execl` function but i have error when i use it

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code plus the error ?

Comment: You should use execle() or execvpe() instead of execl. Those calls allow you to specify an environment.

Comment: usually `VAR=value ./yourProgram` it's enough, but this is a solution if the `VAR` is used inside your program, don't expect this to operate at a system level.

Answer (score 2):

[`man execle`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execle) shows how to start a process. You setup your environment and pass it to `execle()`

```
char *envp[] = { "LD_PRELOAD=/test/lib.so", "HOME=/home/olaf", NULL };
execle("/path/to/program", "program", "argument1", "argument2", NULL, envp);
```

Comment: @ivan Thank you for catching the missing `NULL`.